# Control menu display and page level security using Active directory for an ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, active-directory, authorization

I would like to control the menu display (show/hide menu items) in my ASP.NET 3.5 website based on the user's AD group and also control the functionality within a page using user's active directory group membership. how to do this? menu is stored in an xml file and bound to a control. 
all the examples I see on the web are related to forms authentication. this is an intranet website with integrated windows authentication and both authentication and authorization should be controlled using user's active directory groups. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer in ASP.NET forums for the same question, posting it here if anyone is interested.

http://forums.asp.net/p/1628890/4193568.aspx#4193568.